# qgis ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.pyqtconfig'

Tags: python-3.5, qgis

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Study/qgis3/QGIS/cmake/FindPyQt5.py", line 34, in <module>
    import PyQt5.pyqtconfig
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.pyqtconfig'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Study/qgis3/QGIS/cmake/FindPyQt5.py", line 37, in <module>
    import PyQt5.QtCore
ImportError: DLL load failed:

Found SIP version: 4.19
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Study/qgis3/QGIS/cmake/FindQsci.py", line 45, in <module>
    from PyQt5.Qsci import QSCINTILLA_VERSION_STR
ImportError: DLL load failed: 

CMake Error at cmake/PyQtMacros.cmake:22 (MESSAGE):
  pyuic[4|5] not found - aborting
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:714 (INCLUDE)
```

I have installed `pyqt5` and `SIP` though `pip3`, but above problem still arises.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54962/problem-when-compiling-qgis-with-customizations-for-windows

Comment: same error here on Ubuntu 16.04 + one other:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51478654/unable-to-compile-qgis-3-2-on-xenial-python3-errors-in-pyqt5-undefined-symbol